# Selenium C# set cursor to end of input before typing

Tags: c#, selenium, .net-core

Using Selenium with XUnit, C# and ASP.NET Core 2.2.

I have a test where we want to test that text can be added on to an input and saved in a crud operation.

We do the following:

1. Click an input web element (call it descriptionTextArea) // Assuming a random position in the input
2. Send the end key to put cursor at end of the input
3. Send a string to the input.
4. Click the save button and reload the page
5. Get the input again from the page refresh (call it descriptionTextArea_2)
6. Assert that the value of the text area is the original text concatenated with the added text at the end.

```
  // Assume that the descriptionTextArea has an original text of "This is a description".
  string descriptionAddition = "!!!!";
  descriptionTextArea.Click();
  descriptionTextArea.SendKeys(Keys.End); // Go to end of input text.
  descriptionTextArea.SendKeys(descriptionAddition);

  // Save the page and reload ...

  IWebElement goalDescriptionTextAfter = // same as descriptionTextArea but for new page reload 
  string newDescription = $"{originalText}{descriptionAddition}";
  Assert.Equal(newDescription, goalDescriptionTextAfter.GetAttribute("value").Trim());
```

The expected new value of the input is "This is a description!!!!".

But some times, this fails because it seems the end key did not move the cursor to the end of the input like I thought it would. So the actual value of the input is something like "This is a!!!! description" because the click put the cursor right after the 'a' and the end key did not work.

I could do an assert.Contains() but I want to ensure that the resulting text is exact and that nothing may have been added or that it didn't overwrite the original text.

How can I make selenium put the text at the end of the input every single time.

Comment: Your code is fine.This is possibly timing issue.Since you are using Xunit and due to faster execution sometimes this happened.You can use `async Task` like this.Once the fast task complete(Keys.END) then it should enter the value.

Comment: Check that link https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: @KunduK, I have been using async await where needed. But those two methods: SendKeys() and Click() return void, not Tasks (according to the links below). so I wouldn't be able to await them. This also seems to me that these are synchronous and blocking since they are void.

https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_SendKeys.htm
https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Click.htm

Comment: You can provide some delay in each operation ` await Task.Delay(100);`

Comment: Ok, I will try that but I'm looking for a more surefire solution. Theoretically, it might take longer than the delay I choose.

Answer (score 0):

For ensuring that additional text adds to the end of existing text this is what worked for me (using C#).

```
new Actions(driver).SendKeys(driver.FindElement(By.Id("<yourElementID>")), ${Keys.End} Desired text.")
.Build().Perform();
```